# Can't find other computers in Windows workgroup

Tags: windows, workgroup

There are 4 computers and a laptop all joined to a switch whitch is connected to an ADSL router in our office.

All computers worked fine with each other and there was no problem, then we attached an access point to the switch and changed laptop connection to use wireless to have more portability.

From then on the laptop couldn't find any computer in the workgroup anymore, still all the network connections work fine, I mean, the laptop can use internet and can `ping` and even browse other computers via IP address.

No computers appear in the workgroup except for the laptop itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: All of the computers are set to use the same workgroup, aren't they?

Comment: yes no other configuration is changes other than connection type and by the way all computers use windows xp sp2 professional

Comment: Could you try disabling the windows firewall/any third party firewall on the laptop?

Comment: yes the firewall is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I found the solution myself after just some more manuals!

Just added router's IP to the "connection's settings" *-> TCP/IP -> Advanced -> WINS -> Server List*